# Query for Many-To-Many relation using hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a many To many relation in my resource classes using hibernate. In the Category class:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "category_activity", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Category_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "activities_id") })
    private Collection<Activity> activities;
}
```

And in the Activity class:

```
@Entity
public class Activity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="category_activity", 
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="activities_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="Category_id")})
    private Collection<Category> category;
}
```

When I had oneToMany relation between them I was using a Query that worked fine for me:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Collection<Activity> activities = (Collection<Activity>) session.createQuery("from Activity as a where a.category.id=" + categoryId + " order by a.key").list();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

I appreciate any help that I can fix this query for the ManyToMany relation?

I also used this query :

```
activities = (List<Activity>) session.createQuery("from Activity a join a.category cs where cs.id= :categoryId order by a.key").setLong("categoryId", categoryId).list();
```

and I got this error in stack trace:

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 500 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Exception report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    java.util.Collections.sort(Unknown Source)
    se.softwerk.timelog.controller.ActivityManager.activityList2(ActivityManager.java:64)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
</pre></p><p><b>note</b> <u>The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.23 logs.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.23</h3></body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't be concatenating strings, that opens the door for [SQLInjection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should be using named parameters. More on [named parameters here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-parameter-binding-examples/)

Second, if you have ManyToMany relationshio, both sides should be pluralized:

This

```
private Collection<Category> category;
```

Should be this:

```
private Collection<Category> categories;
```

Now on your particular question, you have this

```
from Activity as a where a.category.id= :categoryId order by a.key
```

You need this:

```
from Activity a join a.category cs where cs.id= :categoryId  order by a.key
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, still it does not work, this is the error in stack trace:  java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Comment: That is not the full stacktrace, in fact, it looks unrelated, please post the full stacktrace

Comment: Thanks, I added it to the end of the question.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it now... Do you realize that neither JPA nor Hibernate packages appear on your stacktrace? (That means that stacktrace is unrelated to your question, you have a problem somewhere else, apparently on the file ActivityManager.java at line 64 on method activityList2 when calling Collections.sort). You should start a new different question for that (and mark this one as answered)...

Comment: Thanks, I think that I needed to mention that I have a JAX-RS project using Jersey. But the query which you mentioned works with a new problem now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379017/many-to-one-with-join-table-in-hibernate-resource-classes-for-a-jax-rs-using-jer

Comment: If you have experience in using REST maybe you can help me again there.