# Example program for many to one association on join table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Please any one post an **example program for many to one association on a join table with xml mapping please in hibernate frame work**.
If already given at least share that link also

Comment: Will [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379017/many-to-one-with-join-table-in-hibernate-resource-classes-for-a-jax-rs-using-jer) help?

Comment: thanks for your reply but i want any example with xml configuration@BuhakeSindi